# Android - Volley fails to send my Params to the server

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying send data to server using `Volley` library but it gives me an error

"**end of input at character 0 of** "

and here is my code

```
public void postPrams(View view) {
        String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

        String url = "http://Urlhere.com/register.php";

        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        text.setText("done Post : "+response);
                        pDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("erorr", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("first_name","Anwar");
                params.put("last_name","Samir");
                params.put("age", "1000");
                params.put("country", "egypt");
                params.put("city","le");
                params.put("street", "10sq");
                params.put("mobile_no", "0100000");
                params.put("login_name", "Asi");
                params.put("password", "123qwe");
                return params;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
```

Please help me why this is happening.

Comment: Log the response and show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Volley's [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1b4858087f25a8033c5136a96b750752b87e128c/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java)

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

You're passing `null` in the place of `jsonRequest` meaning that in fact you are not passing any data with the POST request. Hence the error: `"end of input at character 0 of`. Try changing your code to

```
public void postPrams(View view) {

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    String url = "http://Urlhere.com/register.php";

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, getParams(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    text.setText("done Post : "+response);
                    pDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("erorr", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
}

private JSONObject getParams(){
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put("first_name","Anwar");
    params.put("last_name","Samir");
    params.put("age", "1000");
    params.put("country", "egypt");
    params.put("city","le");
    params.put("street", "10sq");
    params.put("mobile_no", "0100000");
    params.put("login_name", "Asi");
    params.put("password", "123qwe");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: when i am using this code give me error and 
the Toast Message tell me 
"**org.json.JSONException: Value<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String can not converted to JSONObject**"
@W.K,S

Comment: thanks alot this code solve my problem you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Look a the request method. Post or get?? Are you returning a vallue? or blank?.

In you server side try to do echo to parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
 params.put("first_name","Anwar");
 params.put("last_name","Samir");
 params.put("age", "1000");
 params.put("country", "egypt");
 params.put("city","le");
 params.put("street", "10sq");
 params.put("mobile_no", "0100000");
 params.put("login_name", "Asi");
 params.put("password", "123qwe");
```

replace null with params. You are not able to receive at server side since you are not sending any body.The Map in which you placed your params is for headers not the body.You have to send the body in

```
JsonObjectRequest request = newJsonObjectRequest(method,url,body,listener){
   ....headers here
};
```

Comment: Have a look at the source. `getParams()` is for form data. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1b4858087f25a8033c5136a96b750752b87e128c/src/com/android/volley/Request.java

Comment: `getHeaders()` returns a map of the headers. `getParams()` returns a map of form data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void postDataVolley(Context context,String url,JSONObject sendObj){
try {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Volley", "Volley JSON post" + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Volley", "Volley JSON post" + "That didn't work!");
        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObj);

}catch(Exception e){

}
}
```